# How to vectorize the following block of matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Assume that A has bounds (1:2,1:2,1:numfoo ), how do you vectorize the following lines:

```
W = zeros( 2, 2, numfoo );
for i = 1:numfoo
    temp(1:2,1:2) = inv( A(1:2,1:2,i) );
    W(1:2,1:2,i) = ( temp *  (temp') );
end
```

TYIA!

Comment: Consider posting this on MATLAB answers instead: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/

Answer (score 3):

Since your matrix size is only `2`, you can use **explicit expressions** to vectorize your code.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_of_a_matrix#Inversion_of_2.C3.972_matrices
[image]

```
dets=A(1,1,:).*A(2,2,:)-A(1,2,:).*A(2,1,:);
temp=[A(2,2,:)./dets -A(1,2,:)./dets ; -A(2,1,:)./dets A(1,1,:)./dets];
W=[temp(1,1,:).^2+temp(1,2,:).^2,...
   temp(1,1,:).*temp(2,1,:)+temp(1,2,:).*temp(2,2,:);...
   temp(2,1,:).*temp(1,1,:)+temp(2,2,:).*temp(1,2,:),...
   temp(2,1,:).^2+temp(2,2,:).^2];
```

I tested it, it gives the **same result**, and a **speed-up x100**

```
Elapsed time is 1.070547 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.012767 seconds.
```

Comment: I agreee, this is the fastest implementation

Answer (score 2):

I found many examples that vectorized code is not always faster or clearer.

If you want vectorized code here is one using cell array and without for-loop, but it slower and not as clear as yours.

```
Acell = mat2cell(A,2,2,ones(1,1,numfoo));
temp = cellfun(@inv,Acell,'UniformOutput',0);
W = cellfun(@(x,y)x*x', temp,'UniformOutput',0);
W = cell2mat(W);
```

The results are the same as by your code.

Answer (score 1):

A little speed gain is possible using the mldivide instead of inv.

```
clear
clc
tic
numfoo=10000;
W = zeros( 2, 2, numfoo );
A=rand(2,2,numfoo);
for i = 1:numfoo
    temp(1:2,1:2) = inv( A(:,:,i) );
    W(1:2,1:2,i) = temp *temp';
end
toc

tic
for i = 1:numfoo
    temp(1:2,1:2) = A(:,:,i)\[1 0;0 1];
    W(1:2,1:2,i) = temp * temp' ;
end
toc
```

On my machine you get,
Elapsed time is 0.182324 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.162933 seconds.

Comment: More than that, it is numerically stable - unlike inv

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this code an be simplified significantly:

```
W = zeros( 2, 2, numfoo );
for i = 1:numfoo
    temp = inv( A(:,:,i) );
    W(:,:,i) = temp *  temp';
end
```

Secondly, what do you mean "vectorize the following lines"? What is your objective? Do you want to get rid of the FOR loop? Do you think this code would run faster if it were "vectorized"? What is it you're looking for?

Comment: I'm sorry, what's it? I asked you many questions, what were you saying yes to? Please be clear.

Comment: Yes, I wan't to get rid of the for-loop precisely that. Because this is the only line in my file that contains an explicit for-loop.

Comment: But may I ask WHY you want to get rid of the for loop? as @yuk mentions, it may reduce the clarity of the code, and maybe even the performance.

Comment: Because I want it that way, and don't know how to it by myself. Isn't that enough just to take a look???

Comment: Sometimes the vectorized code isn't actually faster than a loop since there are often commands involved which somehow need to replicate, reshape or modify the matrizes to be able to solve the task by using simple math operations etc... So if you haven't got any considerations on speed or something like that, it might not be worth it :)

Comment: It's possible to speed it up x100 by vectorizing the code. Have a look at my answer.